# regular expression for a match to a specific date

Tags: regex

I have a need to find a match for any kind of legit date format, but -  for a specific given date only, that I am given as a parameter.
for example: 01-05-2020

I need it to match as many formats as possible, such as, but not only : 01/05/2020, 1/5/20, 05-01-2020 2020-05-01, and so on.
not match:  02-05-2020, or any other date that is not the first of May 2020.

thanks,
Dani

Comment: you have to define a format or you can not distinguish between `1st May` and `5th Jan`

Answer (score 0):

As upog already said, you must have a constant format for the month and date. 5th jan and 1st may can easily switch places. However given you have a constant format we can construct a regex.

For the format - `Date/Month/Year` and `Date-Month-Year`. You can construct a regex to match 1st may of 2020 like so-

`^0?1[\/\-]0?5[\/\-](?:20)?20$`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iy6jBO/3)

For the format - `Month/Date/Year` and `Month-Date-Year`. You can construct a regex to match 1st may of 2020 like so-

`^0?5[\/\-]0?1[\/\-](?:20)?20$`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iy6jBO/4)

Comment: Don't forget to add a regex for  `2020-05-01` `Year-Month-Date` that was also described in the question =)

Comment: Thanks - that really great.

Comment: if it would also have the family of mmddyyyy without separators it would be perfect for me

Comment: @danishamir If it's always `mmddyyyy` as in, 2 digits for month and date and 4 for year, this is possible. But if it's just `monthdateyear` with any variation. There's not really a way to know. I mean, tell me what is this supposed to represent- `1052020`. Is that `10-5-2020` or `1-05-2020`?

Comment: @danishamir So if you do have a constant format that's just `mmddyyyy`, exactly 2 digits for date and month, 4 for year. You don't even need a "regex". You just check if the number is `05012020`

Comment: the parameter always arrives in the format of mmddyyyy, I need to have a match for the formats you have already covered with the separators, but also  additional formats like mdyyyy, mdyy, mmdyyyy and so on, without separartors

Comment: @danishamir wellp, as I said. It's impossible to differentiate `10-5-20` and `1-05-20` without the separators. Look at `10520` and tell me what format that is, `ddmyy` or `dmmyy`. If you're being fed date formats without separators, chances are that system needs change